# 64 bits kernel weird behaviour

Tags: gcc, kernel, x86-64, osdev

Im having trouble to understand this problem:

I have this code that gets called by a bootloader but when i compile and run a test that should print HELLO, one of this three things may happen:

If i declare another variable of type unsigned the code will print only half of the string (HE).

If i declare another type of var, it will not print anything at all ().

If i dont declare anything, the code will work nice (HELLO).

main.c

```
#include "system.h"

int main(void)
{
    init_video();
    move_csr();
    p("HELLO\0");
    while(1){}
    return 1;

}
```

system.h

```
#ifndef __SYSTEM_H
#define __SYSTEM_H

/* MAIN.C */

extern void move_csr(void);

extern void init_video();
extern void pc(unsigned char);
extern void p(char*);

#endif
```

scrn.c

```
#include "system.h"

unsigned char *textmemptr;
int attrib = 0x0F;
int csr_x = 0, csr_y = 0;

void init_video() {
    textmemptr = (unsigned char*) 0xB8000;
    return;
}

void move_csr(void) {
        unsigned temp = csr_y * 80 + csr_x;
}

void pc(unsigned char c) {
    *textmemptr = c;
    textmemptr += 2;
}

void p(char* string) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (string[i]=='\0') return;
        pc(string[i]);
    }
}
```

build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f elf64 loader.asm -o loader.o

#cc -m64  -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -nostdlib -c main.c
#-Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -nostdinc -fno-builtin
cc -m64 -masm=intel -fno-builtin -c main.c scrn.c
ld  -Ttext 0x100000 -o kernel.elf loader.o main.o scrn.o
objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1

rm ./boot.bin ./kernel.bin ./main.o ./loader.o ./kernel.elf

#qemu-system-x86_64 image.bin format=raw

qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=image.bin,format=raw,index=0,media=disk -m 512
```

if i suppress the line:

```
unsigned temp = csr_y * 80 + csr_x;
```

the code works great.

I don't know too much about assembly and perhaps I'm missing something vital about how memory is being managed.

Comment: To run 64-bit code you need to be in 64-bit mode.Does your boot.asm actually change into 64-bit mode? Or are you running in 32-bit protected mode? What you are describing is often associate with running 64-bit code in 32-bit protected mode. It could well be something else, but this is a guess without seeing the rest of your project.

Comment: I'd likely need to see boot.asm (and maybe even loader.asm) to know if you are in 32-bit protected more or 64-bit long mode)

Comment: Hey @MichaelPetch nice to read from you again. The loader code is too big to post here, i have uploaded it to my github https://github.com/TretornESP/shell if it can help you guess the problem. Meanwhile im trying to figure out if im doing what you guessed. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you attempt to get into 64-bit long mode (it looks okay but I only took a quick look).The code that reads the kernel from disk only reads 1 sector of the kernel.Is it possible your kernel is larger than 512 bytes? You may have to put your complete project on github to trouble shoot.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will figure out how to load more than that one sector from the disk, also, i have uploaded the raw folder to github so you can check it out. (its basically the code i posted + the loader + some memory functions). Again thank you!

Comment: Looking inside your kernel.bin file the `XABI` string seems to be partially in the first 512 bytes and the remainder outside. As you add or remove code it alters where that string is placed (whether it is in the first 512 bytes or not) and is likely why your code acts differently. You definitely will have to look at reading more than 1 sector to resolve this.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @MichaelPetch i will post an answer crediting you! This time, i know how (;

Comment: I will make another recommendation. To limit the size of kernel.bin you should add this option to the `ld`command: `-z max-page-size=0x1000` this will force the linker to use 4kb pages. Right now your kernel is greater than  2 megabytes. This linker change would reduce it to a little over 8kb in size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182678/discussion-between-tretorn-and-michael-petch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer by Michael Petch

> Looking inside your kernel.bin file the HELLO string seems to be
>   partially in the first 512 bytes and the remainder outside. As you add
>   or remove code it alters where that string is placed (whether it is in
>   the first 512 bytes or not) and is likely why your code acts
>   differently. You definitely will have to look at reading more than 1
>   sector to resolve this.

The problem was that the loader file was only reading one sector of the kernel.bin, so the string i was trying to print was only partially loaded. The solution is to modify the bootloader so it loads enough sectors for running the code.

[EDIT]

As Michael Petch suggested adding  `-z max-page-size=0x1000` to `ld` in the buildscript drastically reduced the size of the .bin file.

Comment: A sector is 512 bytes. I'd be surprised if your `kernel.bin` was <= 512 bytes in size.

Comment: @MichaelPetch indeed, it magically worked so i assumed it was fitting, i checked and it didn't, im correcting the last line.